# Custom customer attribute are throwing error at Customer edit Page - Magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, customer-account, install-script

Using,Magento 2.1.3.

Created **an attribute** using *installer file*..

```
<?php

namespace [Devamitbera]\[ApplyCode]\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface{

    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
          ) {
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {

        /* @var customer Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $setup->startSetup();
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'codes_for_apply',
                [
                    'type' =>'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Group code',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 100,
                    'visiable' => true,
                    'position' => 100,
                    'system' =>  false,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                    'backend' => '[Devamitbera]\[ApplyCode]\Model\Attribute\Backend\codes'
                ]
                );

        /* Assign the attribute into form */
        $group_codeAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                                ->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'group_code');
        $usedInForms = ['customer_account_create', 'checkout_register',
                        'adminhtml_customer'];
        $group_codeAttribute->setData('used_in_forms',$usedInForms);
        $group_codeAttribute->save();
        /* Assign Group id  to Form */
         $group_IdAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                                ->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'group_id');
        $usedInForms = ['customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit',
                        'adminhtml_customer'];
        $group_IdAttribute->setData('used_in_forms',$usedInForms);
        $group_IdAttribute->save();       


        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

At Customer edit phtml files... I tried to call

```
<?php echo $block->getCustomer()->getCodesForApply(); ?>
```

then  i am getting the error:

> ```
> Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getCodesForApply() in 
> C:\xampp\htdocs\magesample213\app\code\[Devamitbera]\[ApplyCode]\view\frontend\templates\customer\form\edit.phtml
> ```
>
> on line 32

Why i getting this error  **Fatal error:  Call to undefined method** `Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getCodesForApply()` ??

Comment: did u add extension_attribute.xml file?

Comment: No did not......m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should try with `getCustomAttribute()`

```
$block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('codes_for_apply');
```

Comment: no luck... same error

Comment: Try to var dump `$block->getCustomer()->getExtensionAttributes()`. Which values you're getting?

Comment: `var_dump($block->getCustomer()->getExtensionAttributes())` given null value

Comment: Try to use `$block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('codes_for_apply');`

Comment: `$block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('group_code')->getValue()` give the result but `$block->getCustomer()->getExtensionAttributes()->getCodesForApply();` give fatal error. Can U please tell me.. what are use of `$block->getCustomer()->getExtensionAttributes()` and `getCustomAttribute`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `extension_attribute.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="codes_for_apply" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

And as @Khoa said try to get the attribute values.

Comment: no.. luck ` var_dump($block->getCustomer()->getExtensionAttributes())` given  null value and i gue ss that `extension_attribute.xml` should be `extension_attributes.xml`

Comment: thanks, your solution is not working..... extension_attribute.xml does not effect on `extension_attribute.xml `$block->getCustomer()->getExtensionAttributes()`.. may be we are missing... thing

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue in Magento2.3

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'organization', [
            // Attribute parameters
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Organization',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'is_visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 990,
            'position' => 990,
            'system' => 0,
            'frontend'=>'',
            'default'=>'',
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
        ]);
```

> i have added **'frontend'=>''** and **'default'=>''**  and called in template

```
$block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('organization');
```

then its working fine